# Capturing push notifications android

Tags: android, delphi, mobile, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am using Delphi XE7.
I have an android mobile application, receiving push notiications.
Sometimes, I have ten or more push icon notifications on top bar. 
When the user click in only one notification icon, I´d like to get all notifications to show into my app.

I did the next procedure to capture all them,  but is not working because it´s  capturing only the push message clicked.

Does someone could  help me about this problem?

```
    var NotificationCenter: TNotificationCenter;
        PushEvents1:TPushEvents
    //this procedure is called in the OnActivate event of app the main form.
    procedure getAllNotfications;
    begin
     AServiceConnection:=PushEvents1.PushConnection;
     if AServiceConnection = nil then exit;
     LNotifications:=AServiceConnection.Service.StartupNotifications;
     K:=Length(LNotifications);
     for i:= low(LNotifications) to high(LNotifications) do begin
         LNotification := TPushData.Create;
         LNotification.Load(LNotifications[i].Json);
         try
          if (Assigned(LNotification) and  ((LNotification.GCM.Message<>'') or (LNotification.Message<>''))) then begin 
            Memo1.Lines.Add('Enter by Notification Click: ' + LNotification.GCM.Message);

          end;
         finally
          LNotification.DisposeOf;
          LNotification:=nil;
         end;
     end;
    end;
```

Regards, Luiz

Comment: check http://developer.android.com/training/cloudsync/gcm.html#collapse

Comment: Thank you but, I think colapse key is not a solution. If I understood, colapse key gcm messages delivers only one message from many with the same colapse key. I need capture all messages to my app, not only the last sent.

Comment: @LuizAlves did you succeed on this? Can you please give us an update if you solved it?

Answer (score 1):

Your app can be notified about all incoming notifications if it registers a service as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11332278/80901

In the service you can collect all data of incoming notifications, and store them locally (for example in a database).

When the user selects one of the notifications from the display, your application can collect the received notifications from your local storage and present them in your app.

Comment: I already have a registered service. If the service app  is in foreground and active, I can capture and show all messages inb my service app, and all is ok. The problem is when the service is inacive or in background. In this case, I am receiving the alerts of push notifications arriving. If I have ten alerts and I click on icon of one them, my app is activated and I see only the notification I just clicked. I need see the other notifications received  in this moment or  then, I will have to click ten times on notification bar to see the other notifications.

Comment: @LuizAlves service apps are always 'in the background', maybe it is a Delphi problem. How do you register the notification receiver for the GCM events in your service app?

Comment: I use: ADeviceId,ADeviceToken : String;
begin
APushService := TPushServiceManager.Instance.GetServiceByName(
TPushService.TServiceNames.GCM);
APushService.AppProps[TPushService.TAppPropNames.GCMAppID] := GMCAppId;
AServiceConnection := TPushServiceConnection.Create(APushService);
AServiceConnection.Active := True;
AServiceConnection.OnChange := OnChg;
AServiceConnection.OnReceiveNotification := OnRecieveNotificationEvent;
ADeviceId := APushService.DeviceIDValue[TPushService.TDeviceIDNames.DeviceID];
ADeviceToken := APushService.DeviceTokenValue[TPushService.TDeviceTokenNames.DeviceToken];
end;